# Split UInt32 (audio frame) into two SInt16s (left and right)?

Tags: iphone, pointers, audio, casting

Total noob to anything lower-level than Java, diving into iPhone audio, and realing from all of the casting/pointers/raw memory access.

I'm working with [some example code](http://sites.google.com/site/iphonecoreaudiodevelopment/remoteio-playback) wich reads a WAV file from disc and returns stereo samples as single UInt32 values. If I understand correctly, this is just a convenient way to return the 32 bits of memory required to create two 16 bit samples. Eventually this data gets written to a buffer, and an audio unit picks it up down the road. Even though the data is written in UInt32-sized chunks, it eventually is interpreted as pairs of 16-bit samples.

What I need help with is splitting these UInt32 frames into left and right samples. I'm assuming I'll want to convert each UInt32 into an SInt16, since an audio sample is a signed value. It seems to me that for efficiency's sake, I ought to be able to simply point to the same blocks in memory, and avoid any copying.

So, in pseudo-code, it would be something like this:

```
UInt32 myStereoFrame = getFramefromFilePlayer;

SInt16* leftChannel = getFirst16Bits(myStereoFrame);
SInt16* rightChannel = getSecond16Bits(myStereoFrame);
```

Can anyone help me turn my pseudo into real code?

Edit:

Much thanks to zneak for this answer, which works great:

```
SInt16* left = (SInt16*)&myUInt32Chunk;
SInt16* right = left + 1;
```

Now, to reassemble my SInt16s into a UInt32 (assuming I don't want to just use my original variable, myStereoFrame), I'll need to do more or less the same in reverse: line up my two SInt16s in contiguous memory slots and then cast that memory to a UInt32.

So I make an array:

```
SInt16 newFrameInMemory[2] = {*left, *right}
```

And then copy the entire length of that array into a UInt32

```
UInt32 newFrame32 = newFrameInMemory
```

That doesn't work though, but if I do this bit of ugliness -- cast the array to a pointer, then dereference the pointer, it does work.

```
UInt32 newFrame32 = *((UInt32*)&newFrameInMemory)
```

Is there a prettier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy:

```
SInt16* left = (SInt16*)&myUInt32Chunk;
SInt16* right = left + 1;
```

Unless the iPhone is little-endian, in which case you'll have to invert `right` and `left`.

Since an `int` can be seen as two contiguous `short`s, you just have to get the address to it, and then do exactly as if it was, indeed, two `short`s.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone is little endian :-)