# represent 2 sint16s samples as a single uint32 sample

Tags: c, type-conversion, pcm

My question is related to this question but it is in reverse.

[Split UInt32 (audio frame) into two SInt16s (left and right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405289/split-uint32-audio-frame-into-two-sint16s-left-and-right)

In the link above the op wanted to split a 32 bit frame into 2 16 bit samples (left and right).

I have 2 16 bit samples and I would like to express them as a single 32 bit interleaved frame.

What I have attempted so far looks like this.

```
UInt32* ar = malloc(totalFramesInFile * sizeof (ar));

for (int b=0; b < totalFramesInFile; b++)
{
  UInt32 l = soundStructArray[audioFile].audioDataLeft[b];
  UInt32 r = soundStructArray[audioFile].audioDataRight[b];

  UInt32 t = (UInt32) l + r;

  ar[b] = t;
}
soundStructArray[audioFile].audioData = ar;
```

Is this legitimate and correct? I'm not sure due to my inexperience. My audio output is sounding a little peculiar and I'm trying to by process of elimination determine whats going wrong.

It would be helpful if somebody could either confirm that what I'm doing is the correct way to express 2 16 bit samples as a 32 bit frame or suggest a correct way.

I have a feeling that what I have done is wrong. I think this because the first 16 bits of the 32bit frame should be the left and the second 16 bits should be the right. The whole thing shouldnt be the sum of the two...... I think.

Comment: Maybe your l and r samples should have type const UInt16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change::

```
UInt32 t = (UInt32) l + r;
```

to:

```
UInt32 t = (l << 16) | (r & 0xffff);
```

This puts `l` in the most significant 16 bits of `t` and `r` in the least significant 16 bits.

**Detailed explanation**

If you have two 16 bit samples, `l` and `r`, which look like this in binary:

```
l: LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
r: RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```

let's first extend them to to 32 bits:

```
l: 0000000000000000LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
r: 0000000000000000RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```

Now let's shift `l` left by 16 bits (`l << 16`)

```
l: LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL0000000000000000
r: 0000000000000000RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```

Now let's OR (`|`) them together:

```
t: LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```

*Voilà !* Now you have `l` and `r` combined into a 32 bit value from which they can easily be extracted again later.

Comment: This only works if you have two *unsigned* 16 bit samples.  Negative, signed 16 bit samples would convert to unsigned 32 bit numbers with all upper 16 bits being `1`.

Comment: @caf: true - I left out the masking to keep the example simple but I guess I ought to add it - answer updated now.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take this up as a complement to Paul R's answer, but it was a bit too long to put in a comment.

An alternative solution that may be more "obvious" is explicitly setting the top or bottom 16-bit values in the 32-bit value. You can do this with a union, i.e.

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        SInt16 high;
        SInt16 low;
    } parts;
    UInt32 word;
} IntConverter;
```

Usage:

```
IntConverter * ar = malloc(totalFramesInFile * sizeof (IntConverter));

for (int b=0; b < totalFramesInFile; b++)
{
    ar[b].parts.high = soundStructArray[audioFile].audioDataLeft[b];
    ar[b].parts.low = soundStructArray[audioFile].audioDataRight[b];
}
soundStructArray[audioFile].audioData = (UInt32 *) ar;
```

However, this approach requires you to know a bit more about the underlying platform, since it relies on how data is actually stored in memory. Depending on the target platform and compiler, though, it could be more efficient.

Comment: thats pretty useful. "union" is new to me. I've only ever seen struct before